# How to use pgrep with slash?

Tags: bash, process, grep, ps

I want to make the following bash code working:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="/usr/sbin/some_command"
if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null; then
  echo "$SERVICE is already running"
else
  $SERVICE some_arguments
fi
```

I think the slash `/` causes some trouble but I still want to keep it.

Comment: What OS are you using? On some, it'll only look at the first 15 characters of the command name, so if `$SERVICE` is longer than that it won't work unless you use `-f` (and use a pattern that'll match command + arguments).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it is centos 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux you need to use `-f` to match the whole command line because without it `pgrep` just looks in the *process name* which contains no `/` and [has maximum 15 characters](https://askubuntu.com/q/361104/253474)

```
SERVICE="/usr/sbin/some_command"
if pgrep -f "$SERVICE" >/dev/null; then
  echo "$SERVICE is already running"
else
  $SERVICE some_arguments
fi
```

However be aware that the command line may not contains the full path at all because it's possible to [exec a file with `$0` being empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119929/44425), so in such cases you won't get the desired output

From [`man pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pgrep.1):

> - `-f`, `--full`
>
>   - The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When `-f` is set, the full command line is used.
>
> ...
>
> ### Notes:
>
> The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters present in the output of /proc/pid/stat. Usethe `-f` option to match against the complete command line, `/proc/pid/cmdline`.